# Template MVC application works as website but not as IIS application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have:
- Windows 7
- unmodified template MVC 4.0 Internet Application
- IIS 7.5

The site works fine if I set it up as Site in IIS.
If I set it up as an Application in IIS, it displays a blank page.
Nothing appears in Application error log in Event Viewer.

1. I'm using the same App pool (4.0, Integrated) for both scenarios.
2. Adding <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules> didn't help.
3. Http Errors and Http Redirection Windows features are turned on.
4. I have registered aspnet_regiis.exe -i (for both 32 and 64 bit)
5. There are no permission restrictions on the folder or any files.

I put a Default.html file inside the folder. I can browse to it on a Site. 
If I try to browse to it in an Application, it displays a blank page.

How do I run the site as an application?

Comment: Have you tried to browse explicitly the default.html file when it's setup as application? What happens then? If you can't see it, the problem it hasnothing to do with MVC.

Comment: @JotaBe If I browse explicitly to the default.htm file as an app, it shows blank page. If I browse to it as a site, it shows file contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a problem with the IIS application configuration.

When you say you're deploying your app as a site in IIS, what you are really doing is deploying your application to the root application of the IIS site, not to the site itself.

So, the problem is with the configuration of the application inside the site.

To understand how this works, and you can have misconfigured, look at this document:

[Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#About7.0)

which has a clear explanation of what you are doing, and why it isn't working. It could be the fault of a web.config file in your site, or any other inherited configuration. Or simply that you're not accessing the application as you expect.

Comment: I had the parent IIS site pointing at the wrong folder. I blame late night code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your application.
Right click on your project, select "Publish", select some folder. After success you must place all files into folder on IIS server and show this folder for IIS web site.
On other side, you can publish your app straight to IIS server, with your http address )

Comment: I'm running the site locally (the IIS server is localhost). Even so, I tried publishing the site and it is still showing the blank page.